# Удалять сообщения в окне чата с помощью закрывающего крестика

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать задачу используя только JS.
Нужно что бы возле каждого появляющегося сообщения в окне чата, появлялась возможность удалить сообщение с помощью крестика.
Пример чата ниже.

```js
function NewChat() {
  var FormNickname = document.getElementById("nickname").value;
  var FormMessage = document.getElementById("message").value;
  var Window = document.getElementById("chatWindow");
  Window.innerHTML += (FormNickname + " " + FormMessage) + "<br>";
  chatWindow.scrollTop = chatWindow.scrollHeight;
}
```

```css
#chatWindow,
table {
  border: 7px solid #006400;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#nickname,
form input {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 590px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #006400;
}

#message,
form input {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 600px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #006400;
}

#button,
button {
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: white;
  background: #006400;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 750px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Изучаем язык JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 align="middle">AWENSOME CHAT</h1>
  <hr />
  <div id="chatWindow"></div><br /><br /><br />
  <label for="nickname" id="yournickname">You Nickname</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" id="nickname" align="middle" style="padding-right:1em;" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.style.display=(this.value.length)?'inline-block':'none';">
  <b style="position:relative;
   z-index:1;
   right:1.1em;
   display:none;
   vertical-align:middle;
   cursor:pointer;
   color:#006400;
   transition:.5s ease;" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.value='';
     this.style.display='none';" onmouseover="this.style.transform='scale(1.6)';" onmouseout="this.style.transform='';">&times;</b><br /><br />
  <label for="message">You Message</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your message" id="message" style="padding-right:1em;" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.style.display=(this.value.length)?'inline-block':'none';">
  <b style="position:relative;
   z-index:1;
   right:1.1em;
   display:none;
   vertical-align:middle;
   cursor:pointer;
   color:#006400;
   transition:.5s ease;" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.value='';
     this.style.display='none';" onmouseover="this.style.transform='scale(1.6)';" onmouseout="this.style.transform='';">&times;</b></input><br /><br />
  <button onclick="NewChat()" id="button">Send a message</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Говнокодец* :)

```js
let addMessage = document.getElementById("addMessage");
let chat = document.querySelector(".chat");
addMessage.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let message = document.createElement("div");
  message.classList.add("message-box");
  message.innerText = `Hello ${Math.random().toString(35)}`;
  message.append(createCloseButton());
  chat.append(message);
  
  function createCloseButton(){
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerText = "delete";
    button.addEventListener("click", event => {
      event.target.parentNode.remove();
    });
    return button;
  }
});
```

```css
.chat{
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0097A7;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.message-box{
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
.message-box button{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
</div>

<button id="addMessage">Add new test message</button>
```